# Returning correct value select on option - It always brings me the final result in the array

Tags: reactjs

i have a problem.
I'm trying to create an option and I have a variety of options there.
Now I want when I select something from the list of options and press the Create button it will bring me the result I chose.
But for some reason it always gives me the final result in the array.

**Data list**

```
export const Form_Types = [
  { id: 1, name: "car1", url: "" },
  { id: 2, name: "car2", url: "" },
];
```

**CreatingDocument**

```
import loading from "../loading.mp4";
import { Form_Types } from "../components/Form_types";
import { useRef } from "react";

function CreatingDocument() {
  const SelectRef = useRef(null);

  const handlerSubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    console.log(SelectRef.current.value); // **it give me alwasy car2**
  };

  return (
    <>
      <section dir="rtl" id="dashboard">
    

        <form onSubmit={handlerSubmit}>
          <label htmlFor="Form_Types">Select a vehicle type</label>

          <select name="Form_Types" id="Form_Types">
            {Form_Types.map((item) => {
              return (
                <option key={item.id} value={item.name} ref={SelectRef}>
                  {item.name}
                </option>
              );
            })}
          </select>
          <button className="btn-dark">Create</button>
        </form>
      </section>

      <video muted loop autoPlay>
        <source src={loading} type="video/mp4" />
      </video>
    </>
  );
}

export default CreatingDocument;
```

Comment: You're putting the ref on each option instead of the select.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is due to you have multiple items in `Form_Types`, rendering multiple `option`, and your selectRef is set.... on options, not on select. So selectRef is always the last rendered option, which is car2.

```
<select name="Form_Types" id="Form_Types" ref={SelectRef}>
```

Comment: my bad tnxx for help:)